# How to create route with regex and redirect in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express

I would like to know how to use route and redirect url with params using nodejs express,

If the url is `xyz/?s=test` then redirect to indexRouter
If the url is `xyz/` then edirect to indexRouter

But the regex code not working ,got stuck or any other alternatives

Included Partial code

```
//app.js
var app = express();
app.use('/', indexRouter);

//if the url is xyz/?s=test redirect to indexRouter
app.get(/^\/?(.*)/, (req, res)=>{
  res.redirect("/"); 
});

//index.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  if(JSON.stringify(req.query)==='{}'){
    res.redirect("en")
  }
  else if(Object.keys(req.query).length > 0){
     res.redirect("en"+req.Url.query)
  }
  else{
    res.redirect("zh")
  }
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Query strings are not considered part of the route, [only the path](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-paths) component of the URL is.

A request parameter `/:some_param/` or a regex would do `/[\\w\\W]+/`

```
//app.js
var app = express();
app.use('/', indexRouter);

//if the url is xyz/?s=test redirect to indexRouter
app.get('/:some_param/', (req, res)=>{
  res.redirect('/');
});
app.get('/[\\w\\W]+/', (req, res)=>{
  res.redirect('/');
});
```